# screen update in screen manager

Tags: python, kivy

i'm using kivy for building an app screen with 3 screens.
my main screen ( class Base) is showing data from a SQL request.
i would like the user to be able to update these data using a button.
first this class Base is called in the screen manager which is itself called in my root class.
So my question is , how do i clear the data in my class Base and update it with the new data?

i tried to clear the data  in my class screen manager.
the refresh function is called from the root class.
i have the below error:
'ScreenManager uses remove_widget only for removing Screens'

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from sql import runsql2
from kivy.core.window import Window

    class Manager(ScreenManager):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Manager, self).__init__()

            for i in range(2):
                txt = 'Screen {}'.format(i)
                lbl = Label(text=txt)
                screen = Screen(name=txt)
                screen.add_widget(lbl)
                self.add_widget(screen)

            base=Base('main')
            self.add_widget(base)

        def refresh(self):
            self.clear_widgets(screens='main')
            base=Base('main')
            self.add_widget(base)


    class Nav(GridLayout):

        def __init__(self,sm=None):
            super(Nav, self).__init__()

            self.sm = sm
            self.cols =3
            self.size_hint = (1,0.1)
            self.add_widget(Button(text="Clearing Screen", on_release=self.change))
            self.add_widget(Button(text="Go screen 2", on_release=self.goscreen))
            self.add_widget(Button(text="Quit", on_release=self.quit))

        def change(self, btn):
            #self.sm.current = btn.text
            self.sm.current='main'

        def quit(self,ins):
            exit()

        def goscreen(self,ins):
            self.sm.current='Screen 1'

    class Base(Screen):
        def __init__(self,name):
            super(Base, self).__init__()
            self.lay=GridLayout()
            self.name=name
            self.bout=['[color=33ff99]Refresh[/color]','',"","","","","","","","",""]
            self.data=runsql2()
            self.lay.cols = 11
            self.titre=['[color=ff9900]Market[/color]', '[color=ff9900]B/S[/color]', '[color=ff9900]Volume[/color]', '[color=ff9900]Contract[/color]',
                        '[color=ff9900]C/P[/color]', '[color=ff9900]Expiry[/color]', '[color=ff9900]Strike[/color]', '[color=ff9900]Price[/color]',
                        '[color=ff9900]Account[/color]', '[color=ff9900]Give up Member[/color]', '[color=ff9900]Allocation Account[/color]']

            #self.lay.add_widget(Button(text='[color=33ff99]Refresh[/color]', size_hint=(1, 0.15), markup=True,on_release=self.do))
            for i in range(11):
                self.lay.add_widget(Label(text='', size_hint=(1, 0.15)))
            for j in range(11):
                self.lay.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.titre[j]),size_hint=(0.2,0.2),markup=True))
            long = len(self.data)
            for i in range(long):
                for j in range(11):
                    self.lay.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.data[i][j])))
            self.add_widget(self.lay)

    class Root(BoxLayout):

        def __init__(self):
            super(Root, self).__init__()
            self.orientation = "vertical"
            #Window.clearcolor = (0.6, 0.6, 0.6,1)
            sm = Manager()

            self.add_widget(Nav(sm=sm))
            self.add_widget(sm)
            self.add_widget(Button(text='refresh',size_hint=(0.2,0.2),on_release=self.refresh))
            Window.size = (1500, 900)

        def refresh(self,ins):
            sm=Manager()
            sm.refresh()

    class TestApp(App):
        def build(App):
            return Root()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your code. First, in your `refresh()` method, the `self.clear_widgets(screens='main')` is incorrect. The `screens` arg must be a list of screens. So it should be

```
def refresh(self):
    self.clear_widgets(screens=[self.get_screen('main')])
    base=Base('main')
    self.add_widget(base)
```

Since you are only removing one screen, you could use `self.remove_widget(self.get_screen('main'))` instead.

And, second, your `refresh()` method in the `Root` class is creating a new `Manager` class and calling the `refresh()` method of that new `Manager` rather than the one you have displayed. To correct this, you can save a reference to the original `Manager`, and use that reference in the `refresh()` method:

```
class Root(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        #Window.clearcolor = (0.6, 0.6, 0.6,1)
        sm = Manager()

        self.sm = sm   # keep a reference for later use
        self.add_widget(Nav(sm=sm))
        self.add_widget(sm)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='refresh',size_hint=(0.2,0.2),on_release=self.refresh))
        Window.size = (1500, 900)

    def refresh(self,ins):
        self.sm.refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help John. I corrected as per your comments and it works.